# Proving that $6 \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z$ are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I think the following proof should be sufficient to show that $\mathbb Z$ and $6 \mathbb Z$ are isomorphic, but I am not sure.

The bijective map $\phi(g): \mathbb Z \rightarrow 6 \mathbb Z$ is $\phi(g) = g^{6}$, where $g \in \mathbb Z$.

$\phi(g_1 \cdot g_2) = (g_1 \cdot g_2)^{6} = (g_1)^{6} \cdot (g_2)^{6} = \phi(g_1) \cdot \phi(g_2) = (g_1)^6(g_2)^6$  where $g_1,g_2 \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: The notation looks a bit strange, however, for an isomorphism proof you should also find an inverse to your $\phi$, that is, $\psi(g^6):=g$.

Comment: Better write $\phi(n)=6n$ as the operation is the sum. What makes you unsure?

Comment: Why are you going to so much trouble to rewrite the natural $+$ operation multiplicatively? Technically I suppose what is written is correct, but a teacher is likely to be annoyed by its opaqueness.

Answer (score 1):

*A word on notation:* $6\Bbb Z=\{6z\mid z\in \Bbb Z\}$ and is usually taken to be the *additive* group $(6\Bbb Z, +)$ under addition.

---

To show the two groups are isomorphic, consider $$
\begin{align}
\varphi: (\Bbb Z,+)&\to(6\Bbb Z, +) \\
z&\mapsto 6z.
\end{align}
$$

Then, for any $x, y\in\Bbb Z$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\varphi(\underbrace{x+y}_{(\Bbb Z,+)})&=6(x+y) \\
&=6x+6y \\
&=\underbrace{\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)}_{(6\Bbb Z,+),}
\end{align}$$

so $\varphi$ is an homomorpism.

It is injective: If $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)$, then $6x=6y$, so $x=y$.

It is surjective: Let $n\in 6\Bbb Z$, so then, by definition, $n=6\nu$ for some $\nu\in\Bbb Z$; that is, $n=\varphi(\nu)$.

Hence $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.